# Intervention variable does not show in the result output in ARIMA using spss

Tags: time-series, arima, spss-modeler

I am new to ARIMA. I want to add an intervention variable into arima model using SPSS time series analysis function. I made sure that I checked the box indicating the independent variable included in the model is the intervention variable. Once I ran the model, the result did not include this intervention variable in the result output.

I was wondering if anyone might be able to kindly offer some insights into this situation? Thanks!

Here is the output table where it only showed the constant and AR1 but the intervention variable was omitted. I don't know if the system dropped the variable due to certain reasons.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the output screenshot? We need more details to respond to this question.

Comment: @forecaster Thank you. I have attached the screenshot with a description.

Comment: According to documentation : ‘If predictor variables are specified, the Expert Modeler selects those variables that have a statistically significant relationship with the dependent series for inclusion in ARIMA models.’ https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.5.x?topic=modeling-time-series-node

Comment: I think your predictor Intervention variable is not significant, if you think your intervention model is practically significant, then I would rely on custom model cs automatic expert modeler.

Comment: @forecaster Thanks much for the answer and link. They are very helpful. When you mentioned "custom model cs automatic expert modeler", what does "cs" mean? Would this be a function in SPSS? I was not able to find this while reading the SPSS manual. Thanks again.

Comment: Typo,  “cs” is by mistake.  You need to handcraft and specify the model. It’s been a while since I used SPSS, but can be done. If you post the data, I can help  using ‘r’ software

Comment: @forecaster Thank you for the help! I figured the way to manually specify the model in SPSS. For others who may have similar questions, I go into "Method" and then choose "ARIMA", then the results will include intervention variables even if not significant.